# Simple LSTM model : No attr named '_XlaCompile' in name error

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I am very new to machine learning and I came across an error while attempting to make a simple LSTM model, and I am absolutely clueless how to debug this. I am using Keras version 2.2.2.
My code looks more or less like this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(400001, emb_dim, trainable=False, input_length = 56, weights = [emb_matrix]))
model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(5, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()
model.fit(train_in, train_out, epochs = 50, batch_size = 32, shuffle=True)
```

My inputs were initially lists of sentences that I intend to do sentiment analysis on, I then use Glove vectors with 50 dim to convert the sentences into vectors with shape (sample size, 56, 50), since my maximum number of words per sentence is 56 (is this on the high side?).

My model summary:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding_5 (Embedding)      (None, 56, 50)            20000050  
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_6 (LSTM)                (None, 128)               91648     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 5)                 645       
=================================================================
Total params: 20,092,343
Trainable params: 92,293
Non-trainable params: 20,000,050
```

My inputs:

```
print(train_in.shape, train_out.shape)
>(156060, 56) (156060, 5)
emb_matrix.shape
>(400001, 50)
print(train_in.dtype, train_out.dtype, emb_matrix.dtype)
>float32 float32 float32
```

And finally my error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gradients_impl.py in _MaybeCompile(scope, op, func, grad_fn)
    369     try:
--> 370       xla_compile = op.get_attr("_XlaCompile")
    371       xla_separate_compiled_gradients = op.get_attr(

c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py in get_attr(self, name)
   2172         raise ValueError(
-> 2173             "No attr named '" + name + "' in " + str(self._node_def))
   2174       x = self._node_def.attr[name]

ValueError: No attr named '_XlaCompile' in name: "lstm_6/while/TensorArrayWrite/TensorArrayWriteV3"
op: "TensorArrayWriteV3"
input: "lstm_6/while/TensorArrayWrite/TensorArrayWriteV3/Enter"
input: "lstm_6/while/Identity_1"
input: "lstm_6/while/mul_5"
input: "lstm_6/while/Identity_2"
attr {
  key: "T"
  value {
    type: DT_FLOAT
  }
}
attr {
  key: "_class"
  value {
    list {
      s: "loc:@lstm_6/while/mul_5"
    }
  }
}


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py in _apply_op_helper(self, op_type_name, name, **keywords)
    509                 as_ref=input_arg.is_ref,
--> 510                 preferred_dtype=default_dtype)
    511           except TypeError as err:

c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py in internal_convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, as_ref, preferred_dtype, ctx)
   1021     if ret is None:
-> 1022       ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
   1023 

c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py in _TensorTensorConversionFunction(t, dtype, name, as_ref)
    865         "Tensor conversion requested dtype %s for Tensor with dtype %s: %r" %
--> 866         (dtype.name, t.dtype.name, str(t)))
    867   return t

ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype int32 for Tensor with dtype int64: 'Tensor("lstm_6/while/maximum_iterations:0", shape=(), dtype=int64)'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-936a1189c2d5> in <module>()
----> 1 model.fit(train_in, train_out, epochs = 50, batch_size = 32, shuffle=True)

c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, **kwargs)
   1006         else:
   1007             ins = x + y + sample_weights
-> 1008         self._make_train_function()
   1009         f = self.train_function
   1010 

c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in _make_train_function(self)
    496                     training_updates = self.optimizer.get_updates(
    497                         params=self._collected_trainable_weights,
--> 498                         loss=self.total_loss)
    499                 updates = (self.updates +
    500                            training_updates +

c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     89                 warnings.warn('Update your `' + object_name +
     90                               '` call to the Keras 2 API: ' + signature, stacklevel=2)
---> 91             return func(*args, **kwargs)
     92         wrapper._original_function = func
     93         return wrapper

c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\keras\optimizers.py in get_updates(self, loss, params)
    633     @interfaces.legacy_get_updates_support
    634     def get_updates(self, loss, params):
--> 635         grads = self.get_gradients(loss, params)
    636         self.updates = [K.update_add(self.iterations, 1)]
    637 

c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\keras\optimizers.py in get_gradients(self, loss, params)
     87 
     88     def get_gradients(self, loss, params):
---> 89         grads = K.gradients(loss, params)
     90         if None in grads:
     91             raise ValueError('An operation has `None` for gradient. '

c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py in gradients(loss, variables)
   2706         A gradients tensor.
   2707     """
-> 2708     return tf.gradients(loss, variables, colocate_gradients_with_ops=True)
   2709 
   2710 

c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gradients_impl.py in gradients(ys, xs, grad_ys, name, colocate_gradients_with_ops, gate_gradients, aggregation_method, stop_gradients)
    607                 # functions.
    608                 in_grads = _MaybeCompile(
--> 609                     grad_scope, op, func_call, lambda: grad_fn(op, *out_grads))
    610               else:
    611                 # For function call ops, we add a 'SymbolicGradient'

c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gradients_impl.py in _MaybeCompile(scope, op, func, grad_fn)
    373       xla_scope = op.get_attr("_XlaScope").decode()
    374     except ValueError:
--> 375       return grad_fn()  # Exit early
    376 
    377   if not xla_compile:

c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gradients_impl.py in <lambda>()
    607                 # functions.
    608                 in_grads = _MaybeCompile(
--> 609                     grad_scope, op, func_call, lambda: grad_fn(op, *out_grads))
    610               else:
    611                 # For function call ops, we add a 'SymbolicGradient'

c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\tensor_array_grad.py in _TensorArrayWriteGrad(op, flow)
    129                                     colocate_with_first_write_call=False)
    130        .grad(source=grad_source, flow=flow))
--> 131   grad = g.read(index)
    132   return [None, None, grad, flow]
    133 

c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\tensor_array_ops.py in read(self, index, name)
    857       The tensor at index `index`.
    858     """
--> 859     return self._implementation.read(index, name=name)
    860 
    861   @tf_should_use.should_use_result

c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\tensor_array_ops.py in read(self, index, name)
    257         flow_in=self._flow,
    258         dtype=self._dtype,
--> 259         name=name)
    260     if self._element_shape:
    261       value.set_shape(self._element_shape[0].dims)

c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_data_flow_ops.py in _tensor_array_read_v3(handle, index, flow_in, dtype, name)
   4993     _, _, _op = _op_def_lib._apply_op_helper(
   4994         "TensorArrayReadV3", handle=handle, index=index, flow_in=flow_in,
-> 4995         dtype=dtype, name=name)
   4996     _result = _op.outputs[:]
   4997     _inputs_flat = _op.inputs

c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py in _apply_op_helper(self, op_type_name, name, **keywords)
    785         op = g.create_op(op_type_name, inputs, output_types, name=scope,
    786                          input_types=input_types, attrs=attr_protos,
--> 787                          op_def=op_def)
    788       return output_structure, op_def.is_stateful, op
    789 

c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py in create_op(self, op_type, inputs, dtypes, input_types, name, attrs, op_def, compute_shapes, compute_device)
   3158         input_types=input_types,
   3159         original_op=self._default_original_op,
-> 3160         op_def=op_def)
   3161     self._create_op_helper(ret, compute_shapes=compute_shapes,
   3162                            compute_device=compute_device)

c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py in __init__(self, node_def, g, inputs, output_types, control_inputs, input_types, original_op, op_def)
   1672       control_flow_util.CheckInputFromValidContext(self, input_tensor.op)
   1673     if self._control_flow_context is not None:
-> 1674       self._control_flow_context.AddOp(self)
   1675     self._recompute_node_def()
   1676 

c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py in AddOp(self, op)
   2249             op_input_ctxt._AddOpInternal(op)
   2250             return
-> 2251     self._AddOpInternal(op)
   2252 
   2253   def _AddOpInternal(self, op):

c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py in _AddOpInternal(self, op)
   2272       for index in range(len(op.inputs)):
   2273         x = op.inputs[index]
-> 2274         real_x = self.AddValue(x)
   2275         if real_x != x:
   2276           op._update_input(index, real_x)

c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py in AddValue(self, val)
   2205               forward_ctxt = forward_ctxt.GetWhileContext()
   2206           if forward_ctxt == grad_ctxt.grad_state.forward_context:
-> 2207             real_val = grad_ctxt.grad_state.GetRealValue(val)
   2208             self._external_values[val.name] = real_val
   2209             return real_val

c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py in GetRealValue(self, value)
   1048           # Record the history of this value in forward_ctxt.
   1049           self._grad_context.Exit()
-> 1050           history_value = cur_grad_state.AddForwardAccumulator(cur_value)
   1051           self._grad_context.Enter()
   1052           break

c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py in AddForwardAccumulator(self, value, dead_branch)
    906             max_size=maximum_iterations,
    907             elem_type=value.dtype.base_dtype,
--> 908             name="f_acc")
    909         # pylint: enable=protected-access
    910       if curr_ctxt: curr_ctxt.Exit()

c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_data_flow_ops.py in _stack_v2(max_size, elem_type, stack_name, name)
   4014     _, _, _op = _op_def_lib._apply_op_helper(
   4015         "StackV2", max_size=max_size, elem_type=elem_type,
-> 4016         stack_name=stack_name, name=name)
   4017     _result = _op.outputs[:]
   4018     _inputs_flat = _op.inputs

c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py in _apply_op_helper(self, op_type_name, name, **keywords)
    531             if input_arg.type != types_pb2.DT_INVALID:
    532               raise TypeError("%s expected type of %s." %
--> 533                               (prefix, dtypes.as_dtype(input_arg.type).name))
    534             else:
    535               # Update the maps with the default, if needed.

TypeError: Input 'max_size' of 'StackV2' Op has type int64 that does not match expected type of int32.
```

Comment: What version of Keras are you using (i.e. `print(keras.__version__)`)?

Comment: @today version 2.2.2, edited the post to reflect this

Comment: I guess it must be a bug in Tensorflow/Keras as I don't see anything wrong with your code. If you search for the error `ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype int32 for Tensor with dtype int64 ...` in Google you may find multiple issues relate to this with different variations and contexts. The only suggestion I can give you is to upgrade your Tensorflow (if you it's an old version, of course) and see if it's resolved or not.

Comment: @today I'm currently using version 1.5, I started with 1.10 earlier in the day but for some reason I could never import it, after looking around online someone mentioned that 1.10 doesn't work with windows and suggested 1.5, and here I am. Is this considered old?

Comment: Well if it is `1.5.0` then it has been [released in January](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v1.5.0). I suggest you to upgrade to a more recent version like 1.7.0 or 1.8.0 or 1.9.0.

Comment: @today I upgraded to 1.8.0 and all is well! Thanks so much, I spent hours trying to figure out where I screwed up the code, but it all seemed so simple that I couldn't at all think of where I possibly made an error, appreciate your time and efforts :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using version 1.5.0 of TF initially, upgraded to v1.8.0 and all is working. Issue resolved.